# Customize scrollbar in Page Action for Google Chrome extension

Tags: css, google-chrome, scrollbar, google-chrome-extension

How do I customize the scrollbar (eg. make it black and thinner) for the Page Action popup for a Google Chrome extension?

For reference, here is what a Page Action is:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/pageAction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using CSS3 scroll:
http://webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/

Since the popup is just a webpage.